# Gate- Loading a gapp file is taking time .Hoe can I reduce it?

Tags: java, nlp, gate

I am working on GATE related project. 
 So, Here I am creating a pipeline through GATE. I am using that `.gapp` file in my java code. So, for loading a `.gapp` file, it takes around 10 seconds, which is too much for my application.

How can I solve this issue?

Second problem is that, I have to do `System.exit` after processing a document to release the memory, if I didn't then I got `OutofMemoryError.`

So, how can I solve these issues?

**My code is like:**

```
public class GateMainClass {

    CorpusController application = null;
    Corpus corpus = null;

    public void processApp(String gateHome, String gapFilePath, String docSourcePath, String isSingleDocument) throws ResourceInstantiationException {
        try {
            if (!Gate.isInitialised()) {
                Gate.runInSandbox(true);
                Gate.setGateHome(new File(gateHome));
                Gate.setPluginsHome(new File(gateHome, "plugins"));
                Gate.init();
            }
            application = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(new File(gapFilePath));
            corpus = Factory.newCorpus("main");
            application.setCorpus(corpus);

            if(isSingleDocument.equals(Boolean.TRUE.toString())) {
                Document doc = Factory.newDocument(new File(docSourcePath).toURI().toURL());
                corpus.add(doc);

            } else {
                File[] files;
                File folder = new File(docSourcePath);
                files = folder.listFiles(new FileUtil.CustomFileNameFilter(".xml"));
                Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    Document doc = Factory.newDocument(files[i].toURI().toURL());
                    corpus.add(doc);
                }
            }
            application.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          corpus.clear();
        }
    }
```

**And my gapp file is like:**

```
1.Document Reset PR
2.Annie English Tokenizer.
3.ANnie Gazetteer.
4.Annie Sentence Spiliter.
5.Annie POS Tagger.
6.GATE morphological Analyser.
7.Flexible gazetteer.
8.HTML markup transfer
9.Main Jape file.
```

Comment: What about loading the app only once at the startup and reusing it for all the documents?

Comment: Note laso that GATE creole resources (including GATE documents) need to be explicitly deleted to free the memory: https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:api:factory >Not calling `Factory.deleteResource()` will lead to memory leaks!

Comment: Yes , we can load the app at startup . I was trying to do the same thing , But was not able to do . But Because of System.exit() . I am not able to do that . Because it will need it next time as well

Comment: dedek is right. Why should you do System.exit after document processing? Why not release it with Factory.deleteResource() ? Refactor your code and use document creation/releasing properly according to GATE documentation and examples.

Comment: I did factory.deleteResource() . But still it is not releasing memory . So, i am able to process only one document , and for second , it throws exception.

Comment: You can see exactly how it should be done in the course materials here: https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/TrainingCourseJune2016/ , the very last one: Section 3 Advanced Topics, in the zip here: /3-advanced-embedded/hands-on/webapps/src/main/java/gatetutorial/ . If you call the right methods and it's still not working you probably have a problem in your pipeline (holding resources for each document) or it's just too large for the RAM you're giving it.